# How to fix a log in check?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have created a log in page using html and am having difficulties with a function that i have created to check whether the log in is correct or not, in which if it is correct, it will then take it to the Main page. This is all created however it is not created.

I have already tried editing my code in and implementing my function in different areas in my coding. I have also tried looking at various different tutorials and samples of log in coding which have been very unsuccessful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: cursive;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: #1E90FF;
      text-align: center;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* style the container */
    .container {
      border-radius: 0px;
      background-color: #1E90FF;
      padding: 10px 300px 10px 300px;
    } 

    /* style inputs and link buttons */
    input,
    .btn {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 9px;
      margin: 10px 30px;
      opacity: 0.85;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 20px;
      text-decoration: none; 
    }

    input:hover,
    .btn:hover {
      opacity: 5;
    }


    /* style the submit button */
    input[type=submit] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
      background-color: #4CAF50;

    }

    /* bottom container */
    .bottom-container {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #1E90FF;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;

    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>DIVIDE AND CONQUER THE TIMES!</h2>
    <p>Please Login to experience a world of numbers and games!</p>

    <div class="container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="row">
          <h2 style="text-align: Center">LOGIN</h2>
          </div>

            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="row">
       <a href="#" style="color:white" class="btn">Forgot password?</a>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">
    function check(form)
    {
    if (form.username.value)=="myusername" && form.password.value == "mypassword")
    {
    window.open('MainMenu.html')
    }
    else
    {
    alert ("Error Password or Username")
    }
    }

    </body>
    </html>
```

I expect that my log in is able to check the password and username and therefore if correct is able to move to a different html page in which currently is does not and only moves to a blank page and does not confirm whether the password or username is correct.

Comment: It seems to me that you're using an editor without syntax highlighting. There's a closing `</div>` where it should be a `<div>` below the `<h2>` and in your JavaScript, there's a closing round bracked before `=="myusername"`, which breaks the code. You would have also noticed that one by looking into the console of your developer tools by pressing F12 in your browser.

Comment: I have amended my code and have fix everything that I think seem to be wrong with it however, it it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Connum commented, there are a few issues:

1 - Your `<script>` tag is not closed at the end of the file. You should add a `</script>` closing tag after the javascript code (or, you can separate the JavaScript from the HTML, as I did below).

2 - Your function `check` is defined, **but never called**. Assuming you want it to be called whenever the form is submitted, you will need an event handler, that will call your function whenever the code is submitted. In the snippet below, I am using `onsubmit`.

3 - `form.username.value` is not a valid way of selecting a DOM element. For that, either use jQuery selectors, or stick with the native `getElementById` function (or similar).

Below is a snippet that addresses these issues (removed the CSS to reduce clutter).

```js
function check() {
  var userField = document.getElementsByName("username")[0];
  var pwdField = document.getElementsByName("password")[0];
  if (userField.value=="myusername" && pwdField.value == "mypassword") {
        window.open('MainMenu.html');
        return true;
  }
  else {
    alert ("Error Password or Username");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>DIVIDE AND CONQUER THE TIMES!</h2>
    <p>Please Login to experience a world of numbers and games!</p>

    <div class="container">
      <form onsubmit="return check()">
        <div class="row">
          <h2 style="text-align: Center">LOGIN</h2>
          <div>

            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="row">
       <a href="#" style="color:white" class="btn">Forgot password?</a>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```